# JSON to Hash in Ruby and vice-versa using Files - Parser Error

Tags: json, ruby, file, parsing, hash

I am trying to save data from a Hash to a file. I convert it to `JSON` and `dump` it into the file.
When I try to parse back from file to hash I get `JSON::ParserError`

Code to convert Hash to JSON file: (works fine)

```
user = {:email => "cumber@cc.cc", :passwrd => "hardPASSw0r|)"}

student_file = File.open("students.txt", "a+") do |f|
        f.write JSON.dump(user)
end
```

After adding a few values one by one to the file it looks something like this:

```
{"email":"test1@gmail.com","passwrd":"qwert123"}{"email":"test3@gmail.com","passwrd":"qwert12345"}{"email":"cumber@cc.cc","passwrd":"hardPASSw0r|)"}
```

I tried the following code to convert back to Hash but it doesn't work:

```
file = File.read('students.txt')
data_hash = JSON.parse(file)
```

I get

```
System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/json/common.rb:155:in `parse': 757: unexpected token at '{"email":"test3@gmail.com","passwrd":"qwert12345"}{"email":"cumber@cc.cc","passwrd":"hardPASSw0r|)"}' (JSON::ParserError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
    from hash_json.rb:25:in `<main>'
```

My goal is to be able to add and remove values from the file.
How do I fix this, where was my mistake? Thank you.

Comment: you are write file with `a+` so you append one json object to another. is it what you need? can't you write without append?

Comment: @Aleksey I don't have to use `+a` no. How does the solution go in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

https://repl.it/EXGl/0

```
# as adviced by @EricDuminil, on some envs you need to include 'json' too
require 'json'

user = {:email => "cumber@cc.cc", :passwrd => "hardPASSw0r|)"}

student_file = File.open("students.txt", "w") do |f|
  f.write(user.to_json)
end 

file = File.read('students.txt')

puts "saved content is: #{JSON.parse(file)}"
```

p.s. hope that this is only an example, never store passwords in plain-text! **NEVER** ;-)

Comment: Yes. Depending on your environment, you might want to `require 'json'` first.

Comment: correct @EricDuminil - I will add your suggestion to my code-snippet. Thanks.